# Trying to Create a mostly custom TableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to make a custom table view. I have a UIScrollView loaded up with UIViews. I would like to recreate the reusable cell functionality that a tableview has. And I'm wondering what might be a good way to do this.

I was thinking that when the UIViews are scrolled off screen I'll remove them from the Subview, and when I need another I'll just add it. However I'm not sure what method might be the best to do this in.

I could check to see the views location in `scrollViewDidScroll:` but I'm not sure if this would be the best thing to check over and over again. If anyone has any suggestions or helpful tips that would be really awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason why scrollViewDidScroll is less than ideal choice is that your scroll view subclass will then need to be its own delegate.  That will deny the users of that class the chance to be the delegate (easily, at least).

The better place to check this is in overriding `layoutSubviews`.  And yes, like scrollViewDidScroll, it gets called a lot!  But if you think about it, the only way to detect with certainty if any subview has been scrolled off, is to check when any scrolling occurs.

So the key is to be as efficient as you can checking.  The first thing I'd try is fast enumeration of the subviews, asking if each frame transformed by contentOffset falls within the parent's bounds (using `CGRectIntersectsRect`).  If not, add it to your reuse pool and remove it from superview.

Comment: Good stuff. I like how that sounds. Quick question. When i've scrolled say the first row off of the top of the screen I plan on reusing it by sticking it to the bottom. But allow the user to scroll down to the newly added row I need to increase the `contentSize` of the ScrollView . Is this ok? or should I try for another way?

Comment: I imagine the way tableview works is to ask it's delegate the numberOfRows and to set the content size to that times the rowHeight.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `UIScrollView` and override `setContentOffset`. That's where the `scrollViewDidScroll` message comes from in the original `UITableView`, and that's where you can implement your own logic.

Edit: you might want to study the source code for [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView), which is not a custom `UITableView` but a custom `UICollectionView`.